# Prove that idempotency is a necessary and sufficient condition for a densiy matrix to be N-representable

Tags: quantum-chemistry

As I understand, a necessary and sufficient condition for a density matrix $P$ to be represented by a wavefunction $|\Psi\rangle$ is that it is idempotent, i.e. $P^2=P$. It is easy to see that if $P=|\Psi\rangle\langle \Psi|$ then $P$ is idempotent:
$$
P^2=|\Psi\rangle\langle \Psi|\Psi\rangle\langle \Psi|=|\Psi\rangle\langle \Psi|
$$
since by normalization $\langle \Psi|\Psi\rangle=1$. However, I have had trouble with the other direction - how can I show that if $P^2=P$ then $P=|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|$ for some $\Psi$?

I have been able to demonstrate that if $P^2=P$ then
$$
P=\sum_{j} |\Psi_j\rangle\langle\Psi_j|
$$
where the sum over $j$ has no more terms than the dimension of the density matrix $P$. My argument was analogous to [the one found here](https://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~pdh1001/thesis/node24.html#SECTION001042000000000000000). I suspect that I'm almost there - I think it's just a change of basis that I haven't seen yet. How can I complete this proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A density matrix $D$ is positive semidefinite, hermitian, and has trace one.
Because of hermiticity we may assume that it is diagonal.
Let's denote the eigenvalues with $\lambda_i$ .
Because it is positive semidefinite, we have $0 \leq \lambda_i \leq 1$.

The matrix $D^2$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_i^2$. Since it is idempotent ($D = D^2$) and has trace one, we may write:
$$\sum_i \lambda_i = \sum_i \lambda_i^2 = 1$$
The only possibility for this to be true is, if there is one and only one $j$
for which $\lambda_j = 1$.

So $D$ has one $1$ in the diagonal at the $j$-th column and all other values in the matrix are zero.
You can easily represent this matrix with:
$ e_j e_j^T$. ($e_j$ being the $j$-th unit vector.)

If you transform back to you original nondiagonal form, you obtain your $\Psi$.

Comment: Thank you! I see what I was missing - the key had been in the defining properties of the density matrix.

Comment: I think that what you have described is a pure state, a stationary state (eigenstate of the time-independent Schr. Eq.). However if you have a superposition or coherence then I don't think D would be reducible to the form you describe, or?

Comment: If you have no pure state, then D would not be idempotent. Because lambda would not equal lambda^2.